# Algorithm For Partition An Array into Subsets With Minimum Total Variance

Tags: algorithm, partition

I have an array of floating point numbers and I would like to partition the array into two subsets, such that their total variance is minimized.

The total variance is defined in the following:

```
var = (var_1 * n_1 + var_2 * n_2)/(n_1 + n_2)
```

where `n_1` and `n_2` are number of elements on the left/right respectively, and `var_1` and `var_2` are variance on the left/right respectively.

My question is: Is there any efficient algorithm for finding the global minimum of the total variance? The algorithm should output two subset, each containing the elements of the corresponding group.

Moreover, suppose each element is a tuple `(x,y)`, and instead of variance I would like to find the global covariance of the left and right, defined in similar way as above. Is there some general algorithm for dealing with such partition problems? I guess this should be harder because all algorithms I can think of requires sorting the array, but there is no obvious comparator for sorting the tuple here.

Comment: The question leaves some points open: 1) you want exactly two subsets or more? 2) A subset must consist of consecutive elements of the array?

Comment: @Henry 1) I just want two subsets, although it would be nice if the algorithm can naturally extend to multiple sets. 2) No it does not need to.

Comment: Could you please add simple input and the output your expecting from it?

Comment: @DavidWinder updated. The algorithm should output two subset, each containing the elements of the two groups.

Comment: I still don't see simple example. Consider input to be: [50,100,75,0,40,20,150,10]. What is your expected output?

Comment: You can solve the first problem (partitioning a set of numbers into two subsets) in O(N logN). One such approach consists of sorting the numbers first and then trying all the N+1 ways to split this sorted list in two (because it is necessary for one list to contain the smallest numbers, and for the other list to contain the largest numbers, otherwise a swap would improve the solution). Would O(N logN) be considered efficient enough?

Comment: @qwertyman Thanks, that is pretty awesome. Is it possible to generalize this algorithm to other statistics? For example, I have an array of tuple (x, y) instead of just x, and I want to partition the array into two subset to minimize the covariance with total covariance defined similarly as above. In that case, there is no obvious way of sorting the array in my view.

Comment: @DiveIntoML I couldn't find a solution for that part, either. I tried writing cov(X, Y) as E[XY] - E[X]E[Y], which is convenient because when summing this over the two subsets, the E[XY] parts add to something constant. This implies that we need to maximize n_1 * E[X_1] * E[Y_1] + n_2 * E[X_2] * E[Y_2]. However, I couldn't find any good continuation or any analogy with the simpler 1-D case from here.. :-) I'm also curious about this part.

Comment: @DiveIntoML one more note, though -- the covariance for a set of n-dimensional points is a n by n matrix. Here, with n = 2, I assumed we are interested in cov(x, y), the covariance between the first and the second component of those points, which is a scalar. But this value might not be very useful, since it is not a measure of how compact the respective data-points are. So if, for example, you are looking into new ways to find a good split while learning a decision tree, the cov(x, y) value would not be very useful. Maybe a more relevant measure would be the trace of the covariance matrix.

Comment: @qwertyman thanks. Indeed I am looking into new ways to find split for decision tree construction, but I am only looking at one predictor at a time for now. For the covariance between 1D X and 1D Y, I cannot find a good analogy with variance either, so right now I just use a greedy algorithm which takes O(n^2) complexity. O(n^2) is OK for me, as long as its not combinatorial exponential complexity.

Comment: @DiveIntoML yes, but besides the optimization problem (which indeed, seems hard in the 2d case), I believe that the objective function is not appropriate for the purpose. Minimizing, for each of the two sets, the cov. between 1D X and 1D Y does not mean that the points in each set are close together. For example, if one set contains the points (x, y) = {(1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3)}, then the cov(x, y) will be negative. Maybe a more appropriate measure for the compactness of the points in a set is var(x, x) + var(y, y) (which also seems hard to optimize, but it reflects the actual purpose)

Comment: @qwertyman I agree, my objective function is not quite clear out yet but it is some function of variance and covariance, so the optimization problem is going to be even more difficult. And thanks for the suggestions!